# DataAnnotation attribute for checking equality

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

DataAnnotations: Range, required... got it.

But just checking value==5 or value==bool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't one included in .NET, although you can create your own by implementing the [ValidationAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.aspx) abstract class. All you have to do is override the IsValid method.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you want to see a sample of how to implement a custom ValidationAttribute, there's are a couple of them in ASP.NET MVC 2.

If you install ASP.NET MVC 2 RC the new default project has two sample attributes that you can look at in ~/Models/AccountModels.cs.